# Photoshop not loading fonts correctly

Tags: windows-xp, fonts, adobe-photoshop, adobe-cs4, photoshop-cs4

I'm running `Photoshop CS4` on `WinXP` and I have been sent a PSD as well as the needed fonts. I have installed all the fonts I got into the Windows `fonts` directory.

When I open up the PSD in photoshop it tells me I am missing some fonts, then when I go to click on some text it tells me you are missing `Roboto Bold` or `Roboto Regular`.

I check the font dropdown list in Photoshop and I see `Roboto` and that's it, not sure if that is correct or not?

I then go to the windows fonts dir to confirm all the fonts are there and they are.

See below..

[image]

Now I'm not sure if it makes any difference that the PSD I believe was made on a MAC & I'm on a PC?

**More Info:**

I just tried creating an new document and PS allowed me to use these fonts. I then saved the file, one with Maximize Compatibility and one without; both I was able to open and play around with the text with no problems.

Just noticed it also doesn't show these versions of the font:

```
Bold
Bold Italic
Condensed
Condensed Italic
Regular
Regular Italic (Italic)
```

After fiddling around some more with it I have discovered the fonts it's complaining about are the ones I listed above as missing within the PS fonts list and hence this question is now getting a bit messy and I will create a new one.

**Solved:** https://superuser.com/a/503037/83124

Comment: The best source i can think of to answer this is `ch-ch-check it productions` on facebook. Those guys can help

Comment: try reinstalling it.

Comment: Possible duplicate : [Windows 7 & Photoshop CS5.1 - “Fonts missing” issue - I have the font!](http://superuser.com/questions/387954/windows-7-photoshop-cs5-1-fonts-missing-issue-i-have-the-font-sort-of). If that answers your problem, flag your own post and ask a moderator to close it and refund the bounty.

Comment: remove those fonts. Then install them...don't just copy them to fonts dir..i know it's the same...but still see if it helps..

Comment: @tumchaaditya didn't work.

Comment: @harrymc Substituting them via character panel works, but don't really want to have to do that for every instance.

Comment: @Brett: I meant rather the other part of the answer - that the fonts in the psd file do not *exactly* match the ones that are installed. As that answerer said: Try changing the font of the text in Photoshop to the one you have installed (meaning change to itself, but from *your* system) and see whether this works.

Comment: @harrymc Yeah, I think that's what I did, but substituting them for the fonts on my system; but it becomes a bit much doing that for every instance and also some of the fonts are missing in the font selection list as per my edited post.

Comment: I have added an answer, which is really the same as in my linked thread. If this is the correct answer, then IMHO it's really a duplicate post.

Answer (score 3):

`Roboto bold` and `roboto regular` as well as other variations come as separate .ttf files.
You will need all those files in order to use them, not only `Roboto`.

Try getting all of these from [this page](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/roboto) (first result from google).

Comment: I already have them all installed, see my updated question.

Comment: Does Photoshop allow you to create text with these fonts? Can you select the existing text, apply another font on it, then Roboto again and save to a new file?

Comment: Ok, I just tried creating an new document and PS allowed me to use these fonts. I then saved the file, one with `Maximize Compatibility` and one without; both I was able to open and play around with the text with no problems.

Comment: And how about editing the file in question as I described?

Comment: after much fiddling around I have found out the fonts it's complaining about are the ones I mentioned above in my edit that were missing from the PS font list and hence this question is now getting a bit messy/hard to understand and I think I may just create a new one.

Answer (score 2):

Roboto Regular and Roboto Black seem to have colliding metadata, both seen as Roboto Black in Photoshop, according to this [Adobe Forums thread](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1309855?tstart=0). I couldn't find the reason why, because Microsoft's [Font properties extension](http://www.microsoft.com/typography/TrueTypeProperty21.mspx) reports the Roboto Regular font named correctly as Roboto Regular.

The quickest way to solve this is to uninstall Roboto Black. After this, the Roboto Black found in Photoshop is actually Roboto Regular. It doesn't help with Photoshop warning about missing fonts though. You'll have to change the fonts with Resolve Missing Fonts or change them manually to Roboto Black.

Furthermore, this doesn't explain why Photoshop wouldn't find Roboto Bold. Because this is very old question, perhaps that has already been resolved in newer versions of Roboto. (I added my answer, because this question comes up when you google up the problem.)

Comment: This is how I solved my issue: http://superuser.com/a/503037/83124

Answer (score 1):

The thread [Windows 7 & Photoshop CS5.1 - “Fonts missing” issue - I have the font!](https://superuser.com/questions/387954/windows-7-photoshop-cs5-1-fonts-missing-issue-i-have-the-font-sort-of)
contains [the answer](https://superuser.com/a/387990/8672):

The PSD file comes from another operating system, where the font-names are just a bit different
from the Windows fonts that came with the document.
Therefore Photoshop finds them as missing, although they seem to exist in the Windows Font viewer.

The above thread suggests several solutions :

1. Ask for better fonts that suite the document better
2. Add font-substitution in the registry at
   `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\FontSubstitutes`.
   This way you don't modify the document and you can return it unharmed to the sender.
3. Change the fonts in the PSD file to the fonts that you have installed.
   To change a font in multiple layers at once see 
   [Editing multiple layers of type together](http://photoshopninja.com/photoshop-top-tips/editing-multiple-layers-of-type-together/).
   However, the changed document may not work on the Mac.

Comment: Hi Harry, after much fiddling around I have found out the fonts it's complaining about are the ones I mentioned above in my edit that were missing from the PS font list and hence this question is now getting a bit messy/hard to understand and I think I may just create a new one.

Comment: This seems then more like case 1 above : bad or insufficient Windows fonts. I'm not sure a new post is required.