# Photoshop CS4 not loading all fonts

Tags: fonts, adobe-photoshop, photoshop-cs4

I'm running `Photoshop CS4` on `WinXP` and I have been sent a PSD as well as the needed fonts. I have installed all the fonts I got into the Windows `fonts` directory.

When I open up the PSD in photoshop it tells me I am missing some fonts, then when I go to click on some text it tells me you are missing `Roboto Bold` or `Roboto Regular`.

I then go to the windows fonts dir to confirm all the fonts are there and they are.

See below..

[image]

It seems the font list in PS shows *most* of the above fonts, but not all, and conveniently the ones that the PSD uses are included in the ones that aren't loading.

The ones that aren't loaded are:

```
Bold
Bold Italic
Condensed
Condensed Italic
Regular
Italic (Regular Italic)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, of all the things I tried the only thing that worked for me was to put all the fonts (.ttf files) in the following folder:

```
C:\Program Files\Common Files\Adobe\Fonts
```

I didn't have this folder, so you may need to create it.

Hope this helps others!

Comment: This solved my issue too. When I downloaded the Robot font archive from the Android Design Guidelines and installed them, all fonts worked properly except `Roboto Regular`. Placing all fonts in the aforementioned folder fixed this issue.